# PHP: Type declaration of class method arguments

Tags: php

I got `E_COMPILE_ERROR` when i'm trying to run the following code:

```
<?php

interface DataInterface
{
    public function get();
}

interface ServiceInterface
{
    public function save(DataInterface $data);
}

class Data implements DataInterface
{
    public function get()
    {
        return 'data';
    }
}

class Service implements ServiceInterface
{
    public function save(Data $data)
    {//the problem is here^^
        var_dump($data->get());
    }   
}

$service = new Service();
$data = new Data();
$service->save($data);
```

`Data` class is implementation of `DataInterface` interface. I wonder why this code cannot be compiled? Documentation says that valid type *must be an instanceof the given class or interface name*.
(http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

```
$data = new Data();
var_dump($data instanceof DataInterface); //true;
```

As far as i understand if declared type of method parameter is class which implements expected interface then this type satisfies the needs (implements all methods) and signature should match.

Comment: The documentation you quoted refers to the actual argument passed to the function when it is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

`Service` is required to implement `ServiceInterface`.
`ServiceInterface` specifies that `save` must accept a `DataInterface`.
But `Service::save` accepts `Data` instead of `DataInterface`. That's not the same type, the implementation is incompatible with the interface declaration.

It matters **when you call** `Service::save`, that `$data` is an `instanceof DataInterface`; not when you declare the method signature.

---

To get more in-depth on this: interfaces are used this way:

```
function foo(ServiceInterface $service) {
   $service->save($something);
}
```

In other words, *some other code* is going to receive something that `implements ServiceInterface`. It doesn't know or care what `$service` is, as long as it implements the known contract specified in `ServiceInterface`. And `ServiceInterface` specifies that it's possible to pass any `DataInterface` to `$service::save()`, *not a `Data`* instance. `$something` can be any other object which `implements DataInterface`. Having `Service::save` only accept `Data` instances breaks that contract and would lead to runtime errors.

Comment: Let's assume that i have two different implementations of `DataInterface`:
`DataSql` and `DataRedis`. And also two implementations of `ServiceInterface`: `ServiceSql` and `ServiceRedis`. I want be sure `ServiceSql::save()` method expects to receive only instance of `DataSql` class but not `DataRedis`. But I cant implement it in this way.

Comment: No you can't, because it makes no sense to use an overarching interface declaration if you have two completely incompatible concrete implementations. If you are using a `ServiceInterface::save` interface at all, that means all implementations of it must be agnostic to concrete differences and must all accept the same arguments. If that's not your reality, then you don't have a situation where a `ServiceInterface` makes sense. You have two different concrete classes which both accept different argument types.

Comment: I can pass object of subclass during runtime, but i can't restrict type of expected parameter even if this type is still implements the same interface . It's quite strange in my opinion.

Comment: No, it's not strange. *Really* try to understand the sample I give. `foo` doesn't know what it gets, only that it gets some object conforming to `ServiceInterface`. `ServiceInterface::save` says it accepts anything implementing `DataInterface`. It passes `$something` that `implements DataInterface`. Your code explodes because your concrete `Service::save` accepts exclusively `Data` instances, and `$something` does not happen to be an `instanceof Data`. Interface violation. Not allowed. Error caught at compile time *thanks to* interface declarations.

Comment: Take a closer look at the code that I posted. My concrete `Service::save` accepts `Data` which is implementation of `DataInterface`, in other words this method expect to receive instance of `DataInterface`.

Comment: You're not getting my point, and I don't know how else to put it. If you declare an interface, then all implementing classes need to stick to this interface exactly, else you cannot depend on the type hinting, which negates the entire point of using interfaces in the first place. `Data` is **a different type** than `DataInterface`, a narrower subtype, and thereby it breaks the interface's type declaration.

Comment: Another concrete example: `class Data2 implements DataInterface { }`. According to `ServiceInterface`, `Service` should accept objects of type `Data2`. But it doesn't, because the concrete implementation of `Service` is violating the interface declaration.

Comment: `Data` is not different type. `Data` has type `DataInterface`. Try to execute this code: `var_dump($data instanceof DataInterface);`. Since `Data` class implements DataInterface `Service` may be sure that instance of `Data` class has all necessary methods declared in `DataInterface`.

Comment: `Data` ***is*** a different type than `DataInterface`; just look at its different name! `DataInterface` is at the root of a type hierarchy, and `Data` is a *sub*-type of it. Yes, it's in the same hierarchy and hence it's an `instanceof` it, but it's not **the same** type. You don't need to adjust the type signature when implementing an interface, you must implement the interface **exactly**. What if `DataInterface` specified `save(Data $data)`; would you implement it as `save(SubtypeOfData $data)`‽ Of course not. That doesn't change when the type is an interface.

Comment: We can argue about this all day, but it's not negotiable. *You* don't fully understand type hierarchies and interfaces; you don't need to try to convince me of the opposite. If you have a constructive question needed to further your understanding, please ask it.

Comment: Please look at **Type Operators** page: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.type.php 
`instanceof` checks the type of object and instance of `Data` class has type `Data` and `DataInterface`. Type of `Data` **is** `DataInterface`.

Comment: Hum. And as you said when you call `Service::save` then `$data` (instace of `Data` class) suddenly became the same type (`DataInterface`). Don't you think this this is quite strange, that during runtime it's ok, but during compilation not.

Comment: `instanceof` checks whether a given object is *in the __type hierarchy__* of the given type. That means, if it's an instance of the exact class *or any subclass thereof*. Since `Data implements DataInterface`, it's a subtype of it. There's no difference to the hierarchy established with `class .. extends ..` here. So yes, you can pass a `Data` instance to a function expecting a `DataInterface` instance, since that satisfies the type hierarchy constraint. (cont...)

Comment: ***However***, you cannot implement a method that's supposed to be implemented as accepting a `DataInterface` argument with only accepting a `Data` argument. Because that's ***narrower***. That method starts lower in the type hierarchy; it doesn't accept *all* `DataInterface` types, only a specific sub-branch of it which starts at `Data` and all of its possible sub-types. So you're breaking the contract you specified in the interface!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the following exception when running your code:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Service::save() must be compatible with ServiceInterface::save(DataInterface $data) in test.php on line 22
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() test.php:0

Fatal error: Declaration of Service::save() must be compatible with ServiceInterface::save(DataInterface $data) in test.php on line 22

Call Stack:
    0.0002     130808   1. {main}() test.php:0
```

.. and the exception is very clear about your problem: The declaration of Service::save() is wrong.  It's trying to take in a `Date` whereas the function it's trying to override (`ServiceInterface::save`) takes a `DateInterface`.

You should change the signature of Service::save() to take in a `DateInterface`.  You can still pass it a `Date` object, but you can't *force* it to be a `Date` object.  If you want a method that takes just `Date` objects (and their subclasses), you'll need to give it a new name.

Comment: I can read error messages and i know how to fix it. I think that this is not my problem, but problem of the PHP.

Comment: I beg to differ.  PHP has no problem here.  It's telling you you're doing something wrong.  You are trying to override one function with another function that has a different signature.  That's not allowed.  What *is* allowed is passing a subclass of the specified type at runtime, which is what the quoted part of the PHP manual you referenced says.

Comment: Right, this is the problem i guess. I can pass subclass object to this method but i cant restrict type of parameter in the implementation of class.

Comment: You have 3 options: (1) create a new function name (e.g saveData) which takes a `Date`, (2) change the base interface to take a `Date` or (3) in your `save` implementation use an `assert` (e.g. `assert($data instanceof Data);`).  Which option is best depends on your circumstances.